# Problema con el dropdown de bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

estoy queriendo usar el nav que tiene dropdown de bootstrap, me muestra la informacion pero a la hora de querer hacer el despliegue del dropdown, no me esta funcionando.
El codigo PHP, si funciona ya que lo uso en otro sistema pero solamente lo uso con css puro, por lo que entiendo es problema de bootstrap pero no estoy viendo cual es el problema.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    
</head>
<body>
        <div class="offcanvas-body">
          <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end flex-grow-1 pe-3">
              <?php foreach ($listadoModulos as $modulo): ?>
                <!-- Busca el Nivel 0 -->
                <?php if($modulo->getNivel() == 0){?>
                  <!-- Pregunta si el directorio es #(que no tiene) -->
                  <?php if($modulo->getDirectorio() == "#"){?>
                    <!-- Si es asi, te arma una lista -->
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                      <!-- Te imprime el modulo con la descripcion correspondiente pero no te envia a ningun lado (a href) -->
                      <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"  role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        <?php echo $modulo->getDescripcion()?>
                      </a>
                      <!-- Imprime los items (hijos) -->
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark">
                        <?php foreach($listadoModulos as $padre):?>
                          <?php if($modulo->getDescripcion() == $padre->getHijo()){?>
                            <?php if($padre->getDirectorio() == "#"){?>
                              <a href="#"><?php echo $padre->getDescripcion();?></a>
                              <?php } else {?> 
                                <li>
                                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="/xampp/Proyecto/modulos/<?php echo $padre->getDirectorio(); ?>/listado.php<?php echo $GET?>">
                                    <?php echo $padre->getDescripcion(); ?>
                                  </a>
                                </li>
                              <?php }?>
                            <?php }?>
                        <?php endforeach;?>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  <?php }else{?>
                    <li class = "nav-item">
                      <a class = "nav-link" href="/xampp/Proyecto/modulos/<?php echo $modulo->getDirectorio(); ?>/listado.php<?php echo $GET?>">
                        <?php echo $modulo->getDescripcion(); ?>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  <?php } ?>
                        <?php }?>
                      <?php endforeach ?>
          </ul>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="../../js/jquery.3.6.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Además de lo que ya te han dicho sobre el `data-` y `data-bs-`, mira de quitar ese div con la clase `offcanvas-body` pues está impidiendo mostrarlo.

Comment: ah, también tienes que agregar unas comillas al final del atributo **src=** en esta linea: `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js></script>` pues quizás el script no se está cargando correctamente

Comment: Si utilizás _bootstrap.bundle.min.js_ ya no es necesario que importes _popper_, por cierto. Esto lo dice la propia [documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start) (punto 2). ¡Y para Bootstrap 5 ya no es necesario jQuery!

Answer (score 1):

Corrige lo de data-bs-toggle y borra popper.js
Intenta usar Bootstrap con el siguiente CDN

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-u1OknCvxWvY5kfmNBILK2hRnQC3Pr17a+RTT6rIHI7NnikvbZlHgTPOOmMi466C8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cambia data-toggle="dropdown" con data-**bs**-toggle="dropdown"

Justamente tuve ese problema y por eso no funcionaba el DropDown, Al parecer solo pasa en la versión 5+

Comment: Hola, le agregue pero todavia sigue el problema

Comment: Hola, Disculpa la demora, he revisado tu codigo y al parecer no funciona la versión de Bootstrap que tienes, Intenta con esta :

Comment: <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-u1OknCvxWvY5kfmNBILK2hRnQC3Pr17a+RTT6rIHI7NnikvbZlHgTPOOmMi466C8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>